# Finding the closure and interior of this set

Tags: general-topology

We have the $\mathbb{Z^{2}}$ and we define $B_{(m,n)} := B_{m} × B_{n}$, where $B_{n}$ holds the basis elements for the digital line. That means $B_{n}=\{n\}$ if n is odd, and $B_{n}=\{n-1, n, n+1\}$ when n is even.
The following set is the basis of the topology to use $B =\{B_{(m,n)}: m, n ∈ \mathbb{Z}\}$

How do I find the interior, boundary and closure for a set
$A = \{(m, n) : m, n ∈ {−1, 0, 1}\} ∪ \{(−2,−2),(−2, 2),(2, 2),(2,−2)\}$ 
?

Answer (score 1):

So, in sum, I get all $25$ points with integer coordinates in the square with vertices $(2,-2),(2,2),(-2,2)$ and $(-2,-2)$ form the closure.

Of these, the nine points $(0,0), (1,0),  (0,1), (-1,0),(0,-1), (1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ form the interior.

And the remaining $16$ points form the boundary.